# Turning a slideshow to a grid of images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I am trying to do the reverse than other people : I want to get rid of a slideshow that I have in some pages, and I want to do it in jquery/javascript/css (cant touch the template).

However, I dont really know how I could do it, and what to look out...

So, I want to transform this page : http://www.lauramoodley.com/portfolio/illustrations-2014/
Towards a page that looks more like this : http://www.lauramoodley.com/illustrations-de-mode/

Any idea of how I could do that?

Thanks a lot for reading me.
Best,
J.

Comment: [Minimal Complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No one knows how you have achieved creating the slideshow. share the code for slideshow. Then only someone can help.

Comment: This is going to be very complicated if you can't touch the template.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your reply .
Well, technically I have access to the template, but I thought it may would be easier to do it in jquery by selecting all the li items from the #slider and some other body elements and apply them some css, but I could be wrong. For information, the slider is generated directly from the WP theme

Comment: Hello, so i've started looking into it. It seems that the slideshow in this template is based on : jquery.cycle.all.min.js , available here : http://www.lauramoodley.com/wp-content/themes/perfekto/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js  I actually just want to add some kind of arrows on left and right to make it simpler to navigate throught this slideshow... Any help would be appreciated :)